# Can the value of a Pydantic PrivateAttr be set inside a root_validator?

Tags: python, pydantic

I have the following example where I'm trying to set the value of the [PrivateAttr](https://docs.pydantic.dev/1.10/usage/models/#private-model-attributes) `_baz` inside the [root_validator](https://docs.pydantic.dev/1.10/usage/validators/#root-validators)

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, root_validator, ValidationError, PrivateAttr


class Example(BaseModel):
    foo = 1
    bar = 2

    _baz = PrivateAttr()

    @root_validator
    def insert_value_for_baz(cls, values):
        values["_baz"] = values["foo"] + values["bar"]
        return values

try:
    example = Example(
        foo=3,
        bar=4,
    )
    print(example._baz)
except ValidationError as e:
    print(e)
```

But I get the error

```
AttributeError: 'Example' object has no attribute '_baz'
```

I can confirm that it works when using the `__init__()` method.

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, root_validator,ValidationError, PrivateAttr


class Example(BaseModel):
    foo = 1
    bar = 2

    _baz = PrivateAttr()

    def __init__(self, **data):
        super().__init__(**data)
        self._baz = self.foo + self.bar

try:
    example = Example(
        foo=3,
        bar=4,
    )
    print(example._baz)
except ValidationError as e:
    print(e)
```

the print statement currently displays `7`. So keeping this post processing inside the `__init__()` method works, but I have a use case where I want to set the value of the private attribute after some validation code, so it makes sense for me to do inside the root_validator. Thank you for any suggestions.

Using Pydantic v1.10.